# launching apps (using google apis) in android device directly from eclipse

Tags: android, google-api, android-keystore, launching

My android app is using MapView and hence using the google api's. 
Problem is that for testing my app I have to export apk file with my keystore , install the app in device and then run it for checking the output and it consumes a lot of time. 
Is there a better way to do it using eclipse??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is.

create a a 'debug maps key' using the debug.keystore located on your user folder, something like:

```
    /Users/<username>/.android/debug.keystore
```

Comment: can i change this key with a key that i have already created?

Comment: unless you messed on the project building settings. Eclipse is building with the `/Users/<username>/.android/debug.keystore` during debug. So you simply create a new google Maps key using this keystore to use during your development. Before exporting the signed final version of your app, replace it by the one that you're using now, the one for your own keystore. All this is detailed explained on the android maps docs, I suggest you to read them.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the lines on this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getdebugfingerprint

And register a map key for debug here
https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

This way, you'll get a debug map key which you can use for your mapview during debug.